# empirical quantiles in matlab

Tags: matlab

does anyone know how to calculate the empirical quantiles of a distribution in matlab? specifically I have issues working w the empiricalQuantiles() function and need to calculate empirical quantiles of a rolling population (a matrix that is say 49x1025 for every 100 points).

if you can also give information on how to calculate the inverse of the empirical distribution (which should give approximately the same answer) that would be great

Answer (score 0):

```
% Simulating empirical data
empiricalData=randn(50000,1);
% Quantile evaluation
% For instance: Median
y = quantile(empiricalData,[.50]);
```

Comment: thanks Daniel, but I see I probably did not explain what I needed clearly, which is to calculate the empirical quantile (not the median) of each last point in a rolling population based on the empirical distribution of the rolling sample

Comment: What is your input? And what is the output that you want?

Comment: input is just a time series, say with 10 columns and 2500 rows.i want to be able to read across say 100 rows at a time and calculate the empirical quantile of the 101 row based on the empirical distribution of the 100 rows. obviously for each column seperately.